# Вывод результата при каждой итерации цикла

Tags: ajax, php

Ребят, подскажите.

Я хочу сделать красивую форму, при нажатии на кнопку - отправляется ajax-запрос к скрипту, скрипт выполняет объемную работу (пусть будет парсинг e-mail со страниц).

Так вот. Как сделать так, чтобы каждую итерацию цикла (каждую страницу) выводился результат, то есть в реальном времени как бы, а не ждать, пока скрипт полностью выполнится?

Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: @vetogeri, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `WebSockets` или `LongPoling`.
Ну или на худой конец можно использовать сессии и запрашивать страницу через интервал.